# discord.js How to obtain a "reactions user's" list from a fetchMessage event?

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to figure out how to obtain a list of users that provided a reaction on a message in a channel using the `fetchMessage` event.  I am successfully able to obtain a count on the number of users or the emoji itself, however, the actual list of users does not show up.

I'm using

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(MessageID).then(themessage => {

let MessageOBJ = themessage.reactions.find(r => r.name === "emoji Unicode");

console.log(MessageOBJ.users);

});
```

When I go to call MessageOBJ.users, it is an empty object or appears to be. Everything else shows correctly, including the count of users who reacted.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out, you can only obtain this information after the bot has been restarted.  The method is correct.  Only will show the users if the message was created and reacted too after the bot is restarted.  If you restart the bot again, all that info is unattainable again.

Comment: hmmm,  You are right it does seem to only know the users that reacted since the bot was started. If you do a sweep & the fetchMesage it doesn't even know any of the users that reacted.  surely there must be a way to get the list of user that have reacted (ie maybe in another API)

Answer (score 0):

There is another API that you have to call to get the users for a reaction

```
MessageOBJ.fetchUsers().then(users => {
        console.log(users); 
});
```

[fetchUsers documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=fetchUsers)